# Failed to compile with condition in render function

Tags: reactjs

My React componenet looks as following:

```
class OrdersTable extends React.Component {

    this.state = {
      isFetching = false,
      ...
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <div className="content-wrapper">
          <div className="content-left">
            {this.state.isFetching ?
              <div>
                Loading data...
              </div>
              :
              <div>
                <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={this.state.orders} columns={this.state.columns}
                  rowStyle = {this.state.rowStyle} rowEvents={this.rowEvents}
                  caption={<CaptionOrders title="Orders" />} noDataIndication={<NoData />} {...this.props} />
                <Legend />
              <div>
            }
          </div>
          <div className="content-right">
            <ProductsTable data={this.state.products} orderId={this.state.rowId} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

But, there is some mistake in render function. I'm not sure where.

EDIT 1:

I haven't posted the error because it doesn't have direct connection with error in render function. There it is:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/OrdersTable.js
Syntax error: D:/Programiranje/Code/React/working/bootstrap_table_axios_state_js/my-app/src/OrdersTable.js: Unexpected token, expected , (25:23)

  23 |         dataField: 'Id',
  24 |         text: 'Order ID',
> 25 |         formatter: this.idFormatter
     |                        ^
  26 |       }, {
  27 |         dataField: 'Date',
  28 |         text: 'Date',
```

EDIT 2:

With the following code everything works fine:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      <div className="content-left">
        <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={this.state.orders} columns={this.state.columns}
          rowStyle = {this.state.rowStyle} rowEvents={this.rowEvents}
          caption={<CaptionOrders title="Orders" />} noDataIndication={<NoData />} {...this.props} />
        <Legend />
      </div>
      <div className="content-right">
        <ProductsTable data={this.state.products} orderId={this.state.rowId} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please... always share the traceback error

Comment: Please, take a look at EDIT section of the original post.

Comment: Without condition everything works fine.

Comment: `this.state = {
      isFetching = false,
      ...
    }`
 may be `{ isFetching: false }`

Comment: I've already fixed that, but there's still some mistake with brackets in render function.

Comment: Please, take a look at EDIT 2.

Comment: Second condition has mistake in closed div tag.

Comment: Uuuurgh! Thanks!

Comment: @Unfeeling, Please, post your answer separately and I'll check it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second condition has a mistake in closing div tag. Correct version:

```
       { this.state.isFetching ?
          <div>
            Loading data...
          </div>
          :
          <div>
            <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={this.state.orders} columns={this.state.columns}
              rowStyle = {this.state.rowStyle} rowEvents={this.rowEvents}
              caption={<CaptionOrders title="Orders" />} noDataIndication={<NoData />} {...this.props} />
            <Legend />
          </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen error inside browser's console log using  F12 key ? Most error can be seen from there.

Comment: I haven't run the browser because this is compile time error.

Comment: can you temporarily remove   this line of code :   formatter: this.idFormatter.  I think this is the source of error.

Comment: This error happens when this keyword  is not called within appropriate context

Comment: Please, take a look at EDIT 2.

Comment: I think this error originates from BootstrapTable . Can we look into BootstrapTable  implementation.